# Pickle Error: IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords, python-3.6, pickle

I was making a simple little operating system kernel, I implemented a basic (super vulnerable btw, it's only in beta 1 right now) password system and it immediately crashes after running. So I put it in the Command Prompt to troubleshoot and I get a huge error.

```
    C:\Users\Evan\Documents\pynix\3.4.3\beta>C:\Users\Evan\Documents\pynix\3.4.3\beta\beta1kernel.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Evan\Documents\pynix\3.4.3\beta\beta1kernel.py", line 11, in <module>
    password = pickle.load(infile)
  File "C:\Python2732\lib\pickle.py", line 1384, in load
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python2732\lib\pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python2732\lib\pickle.py", line 1171, in load_put
    self.memo[self.readline()[:-1]] = self.stack[-1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't know what the problem is but I'm using Spyder with Python 3 and the file does exist and in the same directory too... The code is as following:

```
import random
import pickle
infile = open("save",'rb')
password = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()

passinput = input("Insert your password, if you do not have a password, create a save file named 'save' and type your desired password.")
if passinput != password:
    print("Password is incorrect, please try again")
    input()
else:
And the rest
```

Comment: Well you use a `save` variable line 3 and that variable isn't defined anywhere else in the code so I guess that's where it comes from. You either wants to define it, or put quotes around it if your file is called 'save'. Btw you also forgot parenthesis in the call to infile.close().

Comment: Thanks @GregoireLodi, the error is gone but there is a new similar error. It goes OError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'save' even though it does exist in the same directory.

Comment: Acutally, when doing `open()`, it will search for files your **current working directory**. Try running `cd /path/to/script` and then run your script.

Comment: Try adding `import os` then add `print("cwd", os.getcwd())` and `print("save", os.path.abspath('save'))` and finally `print("exists", os.path.exists('save'))`. Do they make sense? Are they the paths you expect?

Comment: If I were in your position, I'd probably debug by adding `print (os.getcwd())` and `print ("\n".join([f for f in os.listdir('.')])` before the open line, as a sanity check to make sure that the python interpreter is where you want it to be and sees the files you expect to see there.

Comment: Now the error was resolved by solving for the current working directory but now there's a new error :(

Answer (score 0):

the problem in your code might be that you are not giving the correct path to the `save` file.so, do the following

If the file is in the same folder as of the script, then

```
import os
import random
import pickle
infile = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"save"),'rb')
password = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()
```

If the file is in some other place, then give the complete path to the file

```
import random
import pickle
infile = open("Give_complete path to the file",'rb')
password = pickle.load(infile)
infile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

If `save` is a file you should declare its format, for example `save.pickle` . If it is a directory then you should give the full path and the file name with its format, for example `home/save/myfile.pickle`.